# Redirect to url outside application on session expire in mvc-4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to a URL outside application on session end. But `Response.Redirect` or `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` are returning null reference action when used in `Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)` event of `Global.asax`.

I don't know much about architecture of MVC. Can some one help me in acheiving this?

Comment: you can't use Response object inside Session_End in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the matter is `Session_End`. When the session expires, the server no longer has a client! So, it doesn't make much sense to call `Response` when there is nothing to respond to. You'll have to provide your own mechanism to redirect, like a timeout, before the session no longer exists.

Having said that, automatic redirects are extremely annoying from a UX perspective. There is usually a much more elegant way to approach this problem.

Comment: I'll get around to writing about in a blog post :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpContext object will become null this is because The session of your application will be ended by the web browser.